# Skype don't recognize HP Pavilion DMI webcam

Tags: skype, webcam

I have bought myself a HP Pavilion DM1 to go traveling with, which has Ubuntu 14.04.1 on it, but now (a day before I leave for africa!) I realize the webcam isn't being recognized at all. I'm guessing I need to figure out how to put the driver for it on the machine.

My webcam works on cheese, so it is being detected, just not on skype or websites.

Comment: instrall the `v4l2loopback-dkms` package: `sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms`

Comment: @user308564 the webcam works, just not on skype

Comment: Add the output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: @Braiam `v4l2loopback-dkms` needs to transfer the video for web applications.

Answer (score 1):

There is a (more or less) [known problem with some 64bit drivers](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-966882.html). On my system I could solve it this way:

1. Install (if needed) the compatibility layers for webcam at 32bit:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install  libv4l-0:i386
   ```
2. Prepare this script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so"
   export PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60
   export QT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins"
   exec skype &
   ```
3. Call it "myskype" or whatever, make it executable, and run it instead of `skype` from a terminal emulator.

The three environment variables fix a couple of bug present in 64bit version of skype or ubuntu, depending on who you are speaking with.

As an alternative, you can edit `/usr/share/application/skype.desktop` and change the line where you find:

```
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U
```

to

```
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins skype %U
```

(all in one line).

Caveats:

1. If it doesn't work, try to change `v4l2convert.so` to `v4l1convert.so` .
2. Check the real paths of the `*.so` files on your system (you need the 32bit ones; either in `i386` or `lib32` directories).
3. On all my systems minus 1 the `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` variable is not needed.
4. The `PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC` variable is badly needed or you lose the audio.